# R- grouping and count?

Tags: r

I have a dataset which has two columns `matchid` and `roundnumber` which looks like:

```
matchid    roundnumber
1522380841   1
1522380841   2
1522380841   1
1522380841   3
1522380841   2
1522380841   1
1522380841   1
1522380842   2
1522380842   2
1522380842   3
1522380842   1
1522380842   4
1522380842   1
```

I cannot figure out how to count the total number of times a single `matchid` and `roundnumber` should exist.
For this example, the output should be:

```
count (matchid)
2
```

I think it needs a `unique` constraint perhaps? For each `matchid`, there can be duplicate values of `roundnumber`, but I need to count them just once. I just need to find out how many unique `matchid` exists.

I tried using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
count(r6,var=r6$matchid,r6$roundnumber)
```

but I don't think it works correctly.

Comment: Are you trying to find the count per `matchid` + `roundnumber` combination? Shouldn't your output have `roundnumber` in it?

Comment: you want something like this: table(paste(r6$matchid, r6$roundnumber, sep = '_')?

Comment: I am just trying to find out how many matches were played. Each unique `matchid` represents a match, but `roundnumber` can be duplicate for each `matchid`. I am not sure how to do that, or if I am asking the right question.

Comment: `length(unique(r6$matchid))`? Not sure why you need `roundnumber` if you're only counting the number of unique matches

Comment: @avid_useR I am new to R and I still don't know the syntax That answers my question. Out of curiosity, if I were to find out how many unique rounds were played in each match, how would I do that?

Comment: try it: freq <- r6 %>% group_by(matchid,roundnumber) %>% slice(1) %>% ungroup %>% group_by(matchid) %>% summarise(n())

Comment: @Fateta woah, that works. I don't understand the code a bit, but it works! Thanks!

Comment: Just write: `r6 %>% group_by(matchid) %>% summarize(n_distinct(roundnumber))`

Answer (score 1):

I think that the table function is what you are looking for:

```
table(r6$matchid)
```

for example:

```
letters = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c')
table(letters)
```

then changing it to a dataframe can be convenient:

```
data.frame(table(letters))
```

Comment: I made a mistake with the question. It is incomplete. I can't delete the question now.

Comment: @SakshamChawla If it's incomplete, add more information by editing.

Comment: @avid_useR Edited. I forgot one important column.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on a dplyr solution

```
letters = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c') 

library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(letters)
df %>% group_by(letters) %>% summarise(n())

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  letters `n()`
  <fct>   <int>
1 a           4
2 b           2
3 c           1
```

Answer (score 0):

using data.table package is really easy:

```
library(data.table)
# asuming your dataset is named "df"
df <- data.table(df)
df <- df[, list(count=.N), by=matchid]
```

Should give you :

```
head(df)
matchid   count
1522380841 7
1522380842 6
.
.
```